# Swipe Image And Have Filter Overlay Along Swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgimageref, imagefilter, snapchat

For a few days now I've been diligently researching how to get swiping between images with filters working. There is a post that has my exact same issue: [Swipe between filtered images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319497/swipe-between-filtered-images?lq=1)

Basically I need to swipe between filtered images just like it happens in snapchat, where the filter is progressively overlaid as the swipe occurs like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j75d7Khf6iM

But the answer did not give example code and my efforts have been to no avail.

I have tried the following:

1) I first tried creating 2 images. The 2nd one would be the image filtered and the first would be the original image. I wanted to apply an alpha mask at 100% for image 2 and 0% for image 1. As the user swipes I would reduce the alpha mask on image 2 and increase the image mask for image 1. However when I try to follow all the example code I came across I run into an issue. My CGImage is always nil (because my original image was not created with CGImage data and I'm not sure how to get the CGImage data)

```
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500); 
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(_picture.image.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage*result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    _picture.image = result; CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    //does not work, CGImage is null
```

2) I was going to crop the image, regardless of a mask, but every time I do, the size and scale does not match what I try to code.

If you could provide a bit more solution than the answer given (referenced above) I would be most appreciative. I am having an issue creating an alpha mask without using a another UIimage (I want to just create a rectangle that serves as the area to not draw on the image), and I am unsure how to get the CGImage data. If you can help with this or have any advice how to design this code I would be very grateful!

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Yea create an imageview with the filter applied. Set a mask along its position as you swipe